# How can I deploy seperate pre-production and production websites with Create React App?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, create-react-app, firebase-hosting

Currently, I have deployed my website to a sub-domain for testing using Firebase Hosting: `test.mydomain.com`.

This test domain contains my test API keys in my .env and .env-production files. I treat this domain as somewhere where I can run end-to-end tests as well as allow public users to play around on the site as public testers. In my client code, where I initialize my emulators for local development/testing, I have something like this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    initEmulators();
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    ...
    // Currently this section applies to test.mydomain.com
}
```

The issue is, that I don't want `test.mydomain.com` to be referred to as 'production' because it doesn't have my live API keys, just test API keys. I want to ideally refer to it as some sort of "pre-production" environment in my code if possible. So that way when I want to deploy my actual site to `mydomain.com`, it will contain its own live API keys, separate from the test keys in `test.mydomain.com`.

Is there a way to firmly distinguish between "pre-production" and actual production with Create React App and Firebase hosting?

How will I also be able to distinguish between the two environments on the back end using Node/Cloud Functions?

I have only one Firebase project to store all my data and hosting info, I'd like to avoid creating a second project if possible. I am using Yarn as a package manager.

Comment: "*I have only one Firebase project to store all my data and hosting info, I'd like to avoid creating a second project if possible.*" - this is your main problem.  You should use separate projects as recommended by the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#support_different_environments). You will definitely want them to be separate so you don't make a mistake in one that affects the other.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson, I am not sure how I missed that in the docs. I created a second project for my actual production code. It looks like I can also enable my Blaze plan here. I have initialized both projects in my client using two initializeApp() methods and their respective configs. Now I have to distinguish between the two instances within the client and cloud functions somehow